# How to change a tile for the tilemap dynamically?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, tiled, cocos2d-x-2.x

I want to modify the tilemap dynamically and I use `setTileGID`. Its second parameter is tileCoordinate.

I try to get it by a function `convertPointToTiledPoint()`, which convert the world coordinate of the point to the tile coordinate.

It failed and the location is to the left of the correct one.

What's problems with my implements?

the resource resolution is 1600x800, and the design resolution is 480x320, choosing FIXEDHEIGHT and keeping resource height/design height.

I want to change the tile in the center and add a sprite to check it.

```cpp
auto map = TMXTiledMap::create("bg.tmx");
auto bgLayer = map->getLayer("bg");
bgLayer->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0.5f, 0.5f));
bgLayer->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width/2, origin.y + visibleSize.height/2));
bgLayer->setTileGID(32, convertPointToTiledPoint(Vec2(visibleSize.width/2, visibleSize.height/2), map));

auto player = Sprite::create("Player.png");
player->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width/2, visibleSize.height/2));
this->addChild(player);
```

This is the implement that converts the coordinate.

```cpp
Point TestScene::convertPointToTiledPoint(Point touchpoint, TMXTiledMap *map) {
    Point point = (touchpoint - map->getPosition())*Director::getInstance()->getContentScaleFactor();
    point.x = (int) (point.x / map->getTileSize().width);
    point.y = (int) ((map->getMapSize().height * map->getTileSize().height - point.y) /
                 map->getTileSize().height);
    return point;
}
```

The black one is the sprite which is at the correct location, while the rock is the tile I change. There is some problem.

The location of sprite is (285, 160) with the visibleSize 570x320, so it's in the center.

The tilemap is 50x25 tiles, each 32x32 pixels. the return of function is (22, 12), which is not the center(25, 12)

`Point point = (touchpoint - map->getPosition())*Director::getInstance()->getContentScaleFactor();`

`point` gets (712.5, 400), and the first is not 800(correct).
`map->getPosition()` is (0, 0)
scale is 2.5

Maybe `map->getPosition()` should be modifed to some negative value (-87.5, 0), which is the position of bottom left cornor of the scaled tilemap.

[image: result]

Comment: Would be nice if you try put it at (0, 0) and see if the position is correct? May also be a rounding issue? Recommend log your point value in and see if it is the correct value convertPointToTiledPoint

Comment: @Yuchen I have add the return value of convertPointToTiledPoint. It's wrong in x axis, maybe the problem of resolution?

Comment: Also log value of point after `Point point = (touchpoint - map->getPosition())*Director::getInstance()->getContentScaleFactor();`? Is it correct?

Comment: @Yuchen point is (712.5, 400), it should be a value based on the tiled map, while now the location is according to the visiableOrigin. Do `map->getPosition()` need to be changed to something?